# How to speed up scraping in python?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tripadvisor

i want to display 10 hotels which are best from user perspective. Suppose user will enter 'pool' then i have to math the keyword 'pool' in the user reviews from tripadvisor then take a count and display the top 10 hotels name according to count. For this purpose i am currently scrapping all the reviews of hotels(dubai) then i will match keyword and display the top 10 hotel names.but hotel review scrapping is taking too much time what i can do? any help? ANy other method other than scraping?this is my code for scrapping reviews :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

offset = 0
url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g295424-oa' + str(offset) + '-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai-Hotels.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'

urls = []
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all('a', {'last'}):
      page_number = link.get('data-page-number')
      last_offset = int(page_number) * 30
      print('last offset:', last_offset)

for offset in range(0, last_offset, 30):
   print('--- page offset:', offset, '---')

     url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g295424-oa' + str(offset) + '-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai-Hotels.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'

    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

    for link in soup.find_all('a', {'property_title'}):
        iurl='https://www.tripadvisor.com/' + link.get('href')

        r = requests.get(iurl)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
        #look for the partial entry of the review
        resultsoup = soup.find_all("p", {"class" : "partial_entry"})

           for review in resultsoup:
              review_list = review.get_text()
              print(review_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use a database to store the data that you are scraping for reuse, not do the same work again.

And there is a slight improvement to your code: use `requests.Session()` to maintain the connection to the server

[Requests Document](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects):

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across
>   requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the
>   Session instance, and will use urllib3's connection pooling. So if
>   you're making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP
>   connection will be reused, which can result in a significant
>   performance increase (see HTTP persistent connection).

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    for offset in range(0, last_offset, 30):
        print('--- page offset:', offset, '---')

    url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g295424-oa' + str(offset) + '-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai-Hotels.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'

    r = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

    for link in soup.find_all('a', {'property_title'}):
        iurl='https://www.tripadvisor.com/' + link.get('href')

        r = session.get(iurl)
```

Comment: is it ok if i match the keyword on webpage ? and not scrap the reviews?

Comment: @Hifza ahmad yes, you can, do not use bs4, just get `response.text`, than use regex to findall keywords, this will be much faster. bs4 is the slowest way to parse the html code.